# how to assgin ErrorCode(int32) to a variable(*ErrorCode) of a proto data

Tags: go

There are my codes:

```
file1.go:
type ErrorCode Int32
var result ErrorCode

file2.pb.go:
type CollectionGC struct {
    Result           *ErrorCode        `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=result,enum=api.ErrorCode" json:"result,omitempty"`
    XXX_unrecognized []byte            `json:"-"`
} 
messageGC := &CollectionGC {
    Result: result,      // a error occurs
}
```

That gives:

```
Invalid assignment from  result(ErrorCode) to Result(*ErrorCode), and fun CollectionGC.SetResult(value int32) is nonexisted in file2.pb.go.
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first test, if  `Result(*ErrorCode)` expects a pointer as its argument, you could at least give it one:

```
Result: &result
        ^      
        - pointer to result
```

As this "[Golang - Asterisk and Ampersand Cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/josephspurrier/7686b139f29601c3b370)" ([Joseph Spurrier](https://github.com/josephspurrier)) summarizes:

```
p := Person{"Hillary", 28}  stores the value
p := &Person{"Hillary", 28}     stores the pointer address (reference)
PrintPerson(p)          passes either the value or pointer address (reference)
PrintPerson(*p)         passes the value
PrintPerson(&p)         passes the pointer address (reference)
```

Also "[Pointers in Go. Short tale of asterisk and ampersand.](http://piotrzurek.net/2013/09/20/pointers-in-go.html)" from piotrzurek:

- `&` in front of variable name is used to retrieve the address of where this variable’s value is stored. That address is what the pointer is going to store.
- `*` in front of a type name, means that the declared variable will store an address of another variable of that type (not a value of that type).
- `*` in front of a variable of pointer type is used to retrieve a value stored at given address. In Go speak this is called dereferencing.

See <kbd>[play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/kdwhV55cj8)</kbd>.

Comment: I have tried "Result: *result" , and now i know what's wrong with my mind...Thanks for you time and answer!

Comment: @Tal yes, https://gist.github.com/josephspurrier/7686b139f29601c3b370 is a good read

Comment: Wow, these codes exactly seize my need. It has clear mind